# Convert non-standard date string to UTC

Tags: javascript, datetime

A client of mine is using a non-standard date format (e.g. `Aug 15, 2015`) in her application. However, when I want to create a date object from this string, it uses the local time.

My question is: what's the **safest** way to create a date object from this string without any time shift. I've come across all kinds of hacky solutions, but none appeared viable for me.

Comment: What do you mean by time shift? The date is local but shifts to UTC?

Comment: You are right, I'll rephrase the question. The date is local

Comment: What TZ does it need to be in?

Comment: Initially it needs to be in zulu